# PHP　HTMLコードから特定のclassを持つタグと中身を消したい

Tags: php, html

HTMLパースについての質問です
[正規表現　PHPで特定のタグをけしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/19279/%E6%AD%A3%E8%A6%8F%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE-php%E3%81%A7%E7%89%B9%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%AE%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0%E3%82%92%E3%81%91%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)
前回の質問の結果から、パースについて調べて、少し理解しました

ソース前提

```
    $html = file_get_contents($target);/読み込む
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->formatOutput = true;
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $doc->documentEncoding = 'UTF-8';
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
```

例1）

```
    foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@class="hoge"]') as $node) {
            print_r($node);
    }
```

上記で　class 名が　hoge　の　div の中身を取り出せることはわかりました。
文字列) `<div class="hoge">txtxtxtxt</div>`
取り出す内容）`txtxtxtxt`

また、次のように書くと　すべてのdiv タグの中身を削除できることもわかります
例2）

```
     $scripts = iterator_to_array($doc->getElementsByTagName('div'));//タグの検索
        foreach ($scripts as $s) {
        $s->parentNode->removeChild($s);
    }
```

今回質問したいのは、「特定のクラス名を持ったタグ」の中身を
タグも含めて削除したい場合にはどうしたら良いのでしょうか？

例1）のように　タグ内のクラスを指定して検索し、
更に検索に一致したクラスの中身を消したいです。
`<div class="hoge">~~~~~~~</div>` の中身をすべて消したいです

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@class="hoge"]') as $node) {
        print_r($node);
}
```

を

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@class="hoge"]') as $node) {
        $node->nodeValue = "";
}
```

に変更してみてください。

```
echo $doc->saveHTML($doc->documentElement);
```

の結果が変わるはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試したところ
    <div class="hoge">あああ、いいい</div>
に対しての結果は
    <div class="hoge"></div>
となります。
クラス名が残ってしまうのですが、このクラス名を含めたdivタグも消したい場合にはどうしたら良いのでしょうか？

Comment: foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@class="hoge"]') as $node) {

$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);

}

でできました。